# representing $(\frac{x}{2-x})^3$ as a power series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

find the power series representation for$$f(x)=\left(\frac{x}{2-x}\right)^{3}$$
I have $$\frac{1}{(1+x)^{3}}=-\frac{d}{dx}\frac{2}{(1+x)^{2}}=\frac{1}{2}\sum(-1)^{n}(n+2)(n+1)x^{n}$$

then got this
$$\frac{1}{8}\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{x}{2}}\right)^{3}
                    =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n+4}}(n+2)(n+1)x^{n+3}$$
However, when I use the computer to sum it, it doesn't give me back $$f(x)=\left(\frac{x}{2-x}\right)^{3}$$
instead, it gives me
$$f(x)=-\frac{x^{3}}{(-2+x)^{3}}$$

Comment: $$\left(\frac{x}{2-x}\right)^3 = \frac{x^3}{(2-x)^3} = \frac{x^3}{(-1)^3(-2+x)^3} = -\frac{x^{3}}{(-2+x)^{3}}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this problem,
the generalized binomial theorem
is your friend.

It states that,
for any real $a$,
$(1+x)^a
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{a}{n} x^n
$
for $|x| < 1$.

In this,
$\binom{a}{n}
=\dfrac{a(a-1)...(a-n+1)}{n!}
$.

When $a$ is  negative integer,
$a=-m$,

$\begin{array}\\
\binom{a}{n}
&=\dfrac{a(a-1)...(a-n+1)}{n!}\\
&=\dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(a-k)}{n!}\\
&=\dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(-m-k)}{n!}\\
&=(-1)^n\dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(m+k)}{n!}\\
&=(-1)^n\dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(m+n-1-k)}{n!}\\
&=(-1)^n\dfrac{(m+n-1)!}{(m-1)!n!}\\
&=(-1)^n\binom{m+n-1}{m-1}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$(1+x)^{-m}
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n\binom{m+n-1}{m-1} x^n
$.

If we put $-x$ for $x$,
as your problem has,
we get
$(1-x)^{-m}
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n\binom{m+n-1}{m-1} (-x)^n
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{m+n-1}{m-1} x^n
$.

In your case,
starting as you have done,
but using this formula,
we get

$\begin{array}\\
f(x)
&=\left(\dfrac{x}{2-x}\right)^{3}\\
&=\dfrac{x^3}{8}(1-x/2)^{-3}\\
&=\dfrac{x^3}{8}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{3+n-1}{2} (x/2)^n\\
&=\dfrac{x^3}{8}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{n+2}{2} (x/2)^n\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: @ marty cohen, this is pretty neat, I tested with Mathematica and the result is the same as I would use a regular power series method. However, in the proof, I do get a little confused on the 5th line onward. $$(-1)^{n}\frac{\prod^{n-1}_{k=0}(m+n-1-k)}{n!}$$ how did this come from the previous step $$(-1)^{n}\frac{\prod^{n-1}_{k=0}(m+k)}{n!}$$

Comment: Replace k by n-1-k. This reverses the order of the product.